# Export users data from outlook global address list to text or excel or csv file

Tags: powershell, outlook

we have to export users data like name, mobile number, title etc. from outlook application Address Book (From 2 Global address list Group) by using power shell script  or batch file, to output file might be a CSV or text or excel. please help me any one by providing required power shell  script to solve this problem.

thanks

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. What have **you** tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Outlook from PowerShell to export contacts. See [Outlook Email Automation with PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/outlook-email-automation-with-powershell/) to get started quickly.